# sympy nonlinsolve hangs on simple system of equations

Tags: python, sympy

I am new to sympy and am trying to solve a relatively simple system of equations with it:

```
import sympy
A, B, I, AI, BI, A0, B0, I0, k1, k2, k3, k4 = sympy.symbols('A B I AI BI A_0 B_0 I_0 k1 k2 k3 k4', real=True)
eqs = [A0 - AI - A,
B0 - BI - B,
I0 - AI - BI - I,
k1*(A0 - AI)*I - k2*AI,
k3*(B0 - BI)*I - k4*BI]
```

If I look for a solution for `A,B,I`, it works:

```
# this works
result = sympy.nonlinsolve(eqs, (A,B,I))
print(result)
```

giving the result `FiniteSet((-AI + A_0, -BI + B_0, -AI - BI + I_0))`, but if I ask for solutions for variables `AI,BI,A,B,I` in terms of the other variables, it seems to hang:

```
# this hangs
result = sympy.nonlinsolve(eqs, (AI,BI,A,B,I))
```

What am I doing wrong here?

(this is using `sympy '1.6.2'`)

*edit:* in response to @Oscar Benjamin 's helpful suggestions here is an attempt to solve the original system in two ways: (1) by substituting in the variables that have linear solutions into the equations, (2) by simplifying the problem and assuming that 3 of the 7 variables that we want our solution to be a function of are known. both methods give what mostly wrong answers: nans and non-real solutions. is there a way around this?

```
import sympy
from sympy import solve, factor, roots, nonlinsolve
A, B, I, AI, BI, A0, B0, I0, k1, k2, k3, k4 = sympy.symbols('A B I AI BI A_0 B_0 I_0 k1 k2 k3 k4', real=True)
eqs = [A0 - AI - A,
B0 - BI - B,
I0 - AI - BI - I,
k1*(A0 - AI)*I - k2*AI,
k3*(B0 - BI)*I - k4*BI]

print("trying to solve original system:")
# solve linear equations and substitute their solutions in
((As, Bs, Is),) = nonlinsolve(eqs, (A,B,I))
eqs2 = [eq.subs({A:As,B:Bs,I:Is}) for eq in eqs]
eq1, eq2 = eqs2[3:]
p = eq1.subs(AI, solve(eq2, AI)[0]).as_numer_denom()[0].expand().collect(BI)
BI1, BI2, BI3, BI4 = roots(p, BI)

def eval_solns(inputs, roots):
    for vals in inputs:
        for n, root in enumerate(roots):
            print("root %d yields: " %(n+1))
            print(root.subs(vals))

inputs = [{A0: 100, B0: 100, I0: 100, k1: 0.1, k2: 0.1, k3: 0.1, k4: 0.1},
          {A0: 100, B0: 100, I0: 100, k1: 0.2, k2: 0.1, k3: 0.3, k4: 0.4}]
# all of these give wrong, non-real solutions to the system
orig_roots = [BI1, BI2, BI3, BI4]
eval_solns(inputs, orig_roots)

# second try: simplify the problem by assuming A0, B0, I0 are given
# substitute them in
eqs2 = [eq.subs({A:As,B:Bs,I:Is}) for eq in eqs2]
eqs2 = [eq.subs({A0: 100, B0: 100, I0: 100}) for eq in eqs2]
eq1, eq2 = eqs2[3:]     
print("*\ntrying simpler system with A0,B0,I0 given: ")
print(eqs2)
p = eq1.subs(AI, solve(eq2, AI)[0]).as_numer_denom()[0].expand().collect(BI)                                                          
BI1, BI2, BI3, BI4 = roots(p, BI)
new_roots = [BI1, BI2, BI3, BI4]
# solve the simpler system
new_inputs = [{k1: 0.1, k2: 0.1, k3: 0.1, k4: 0.1},
              {k1: 0.2, k2: 0.1, k3: 0.3, k4: 0.4},
              {k1: 0.05, k2: 1.0, k3: 1.0, k4: 1.2}]
# all of these answers are wrong
eval_solns(new_inputs, new_roots)
```

the output I get includes:

```
...
trying simpler system with A0,B0,I0 given: 
[0, 0, 0, -AI*k2 + k1*(100 - AI)*(-AI - BI + 100), -BI*k4 + k3*(100 - BI)*(-AI - BI + 100)]
root 1 yields: 
100
root 2 yields: 
nan
root 3 yields: 
nan
root 4 yields: 
nan
root 1 yields: 
100
root 2 yields: 
-6.22222222222222 - 33.1666666666667*(9.77105856678793 + 8.49476415953825*I)**(1/3) - 182.875860785409/(9.77105856678793 + 8.49476415953825*I)**(1/3)
root 3 yields: 
-6.22222222222222 - 33.1666666666667*(-1/2 + sqrt(3)*I/2)*(9.77105856678793 + 8.49476415953825*I)**(1/3) - 182.875860785409/((-1/2 + sqrt(3)*I/2)*(9.77105856678793 + 8.49476415953825*I)**(1/3))
root 4 yields: 
-6.22222222222222 - 182.875860785409/((-1/2 - sqrt(3)*I/2)*(9.77105856678793 + 8.49476415953825*I)**(1/3)) - 33.1666666666667*(-1/2 - sqrt(3)*I/2)*(9.77105856678793 + 8.49476415953825*I)**(1/3)
root 1 yields: 
100
root 2 yields: 
104.655319148936 - 100*(-0.00146514175733681 + 0.00423691411709115*I)**(1/3) - 2.718847623359/(-0.00146514175733681 + 0.00423691411709115*I)**(1/3)
root 3 yields: 
104.655319148936 - 100*(-1/2 + sqrt(3)*I/2)*(-0.00146514175733681 + 0.00423691411709115*I)**(1/3) - 2.718847623359/((-1/2 + sqrt(3)*I/2)*(-0.00146514175733681 + 0.00423691411709115*I)**(1/3))
root 4 yields: 
104.655319148936 - 2.718847623359/((-1/2 - sqrt(3)*I/2)*(-0.00146514175733681 + 0.00423691411709115*I)**(1/3)) - 100*(-1/2 - sqrt(3)*I/2)*(-0.00146514175733681 + 0.00423691411709115*I)**(1/3)
```

in this system, all variables are positive reals and all solutions should be real. declaring the first part in sympy with `positive=True`, as below, does not make a difference:

```
A, B, I, AI, BI, A0, B0, I0, k1, k2, k3, k4 = sympy.symbols('A B I AI BI A_0 B_0 I_0 k1 k2 k3 k4', real=True, positive=True)
```

ie. all the answers are still incorrect.

*edit 2:* to clarify, I *am* interested in the analytic solution and still don't understand why it's too complicated to be derived (and then used with actual values plugged in) in sympy. The reason I want the analytic solution is so that I can directly solve for particular values of k1, k2, k3, k4 given certain settings of A0, B0, I0. This is why it's okay to get the analytic solution given that A0, B0, and I0 are known. however, getting numerical solutions when all of A0, B0, I0, k1, k2, k3, k4 are given isn't what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might look simple but this boils down to a cubic with symbolic coefficients so although a solution can be found algebraically it will not be simple. In this case `nonlinsolve` is slow while computing a large Groebner basis. There is a quicker way to get to the solution though.

First solve the trivial linear equations for `A`, `B`, and `I`:

```
In [55]: ((As, Bs, Is),) = nonlinsolve(eqs, (A,B,I))                                                                                           

In [56]: As                                                                                                                                    
Out[56]: -AI + A₀

In [57]: Bs                                                                                                                                    
Out[57]: -BI + B₀

In [58]: Is                                                                                                                                    
Out[58]: -AI - BI + I₀
```

We can now eliminate those unknowns and equations from the system:

```
In [59]: eqs2 = [eq.subs({A:As,B:Bs,I:Is}) for eq in eqs]                                                                                      

In [60]: eqs2                                                                                                                                  
Out[60]: [0, 0, 0, -AI⋅k₂ + k₁⋅(-AI + A₀)⋅(-AI - BI + I₀), -BI⋅k₄ + k₃⋅(-BI + B₀)⋅(-AI - BI + I₀)]

In [61]: eq1, eq2 = eqs2[3:]                                                                                                                   

In [62]: eq1                                                                                                                                   
Out[62]: -AI⋅k₂ + k₁⋅(-AI + A₀)⋅(-AI - BI + I₀)

In [63]: eq2                                                                                                                                   
Out[63]: -BI⋅k₄ + k₃⋅(-BI + B₀)⋅(-AI - BI + I₀)
```

At this point we have a system of quadratic multivariate polynomials in `AI` and `BI`. We can solve `eq2` for `AI` (since it is linear in `AI`) and substitute that into `eq1` to get an equation in `BI` only:

```
In [68]: solve(eq2, AI)                                                                                                                        
Out[68]: 
⎡    2                                            ⎤
⎢- BI ⋅k₃ + BI⋅B₀⋅k₃ + BI⋅I₀⋅k₃ + BI⋅k₄ - B₀⋅I₀⋅k₃⎥
⎢─────────────────────────────────────────────────⎥
⎣                   k₃⋅(BI - B₀)                  ⎦

In [69]: eq1.subs(AI, solve(eq2, AI)[0])                                                                                                       
Out[69]: 
   ⎛         2                                            ⎞ ⎛               2                                            ⎞      ⎛    2       
   ⎜     - BI ⋅k₃ + BI⋅B₀⋅k₃ + BI⋅I₀⋅k₃ + BI⋅k₄ - B₀⋅I₀⋅k₃⎟ ⎜           - BI ⋅k₃ + BI⋅B₀⋅k₃ + BI⋅I₀⋅k₃ + BI⋅k₄ - B₀⋅I₀⋅k₃⎟   k₂⋅⎝- BI ⋅k₃ + B
k₁⋅⎜A₀ - ─────────────────────────────────────────────────⎟⋅⎜-BI + I₀ - ─────────────────────────────────────────────────⎟ - ────────────────
   ⎝                        k₃⋅(BI - B₀)                  ⎠ ⎝                              k₃⋅(BI - B₀)                  ⎠                   

                                     ⎞
I⋅B₀⋅k₃ + BI⋅I₀⋅k₃ + BI⋅k₄ - B₀⋅I₀⋅k₃⎠
──────────────────────────────────────
     k₃⋅(BI - B₀)
```

We can reduce this down to a quartic:

```
In [73]: p = eq1.subs(AI, solve(eq2, AI)[0]).as_numer_denom()[0].expand().collect(BI)                                                          

In [74]: p                                                                                                                                     
Out[74]: 
  4 ⎛       2           3⎞     3 ⎛          2                2                3           2              3           2        2   ⎞     2 ⎛  
BI ⋅⎝- k₁⋅k₃ ⋅k₄ + k₂⋅k₃ ⎠ + BI ⋅⎝- A₀⋅k₁⋅k₃ ⋅k₄ + 2⋅B₀⋅k₁⋅k₃ ⋅k₄ - 3⋅B₀⋅k₂⋅k₃  + I₀⋅k₁⋅k₃ ⋅k₄ - I₀⋅k₂⋅k₃  + k₁⋅k₃⋅k₄  - k₂⋅k₃ ⋅k₄⎠ + BI ⋅⎝2⋅

           2        2      2          2      3                2                   3              2             2   ⎞      ⎛       2      2   
A₀⋅B₀⋅k₁⋅k₃ ⋅k₄ - B₀ ⋅k₁⋅k₃ ⋅k₄ + 3⋅B₀ ⋅k₂⋅k₃  - 2⋅B₀⋅I₀⋅k₁⋅k₃ ⋅k₄ + 3⋅B₀⋅I₀⋅k₂⋅k₃  - B₀⋅k₁⋅k₃⋅k₄  + 2⋅B₀⋅k₂⋅k₃ ⋅k₄⎠ + BI⋅⎝- A₀⋅B₀ ⋅k₁⋅k₃ ⋅k₄

     3      3     2         2          2         3     2      2   ⎞     3         3
 - B₀ ⋅k₂⋅k₃  + B₀ ⋅I₀⋅k₁⋅k₃ ⋅k₄ - 3⋅B₀ ⋅I₀⋅k₂⋅k₃  - B₀ ⋅k₂⋅k₃ ⋅k₄⎠ + B₀ ⋅I₀⋅k₂⋅k₃
```

A simple call to `factor` shows that one of the four roots is just `BI = B0`:

```
In [84]: factor(p)                                                                                                                             
Out[84]: 
              ⎛     2                                  3              3      2     2                   2         2     2                 2   
-k₃⋅(BI - B₀)⋅⎝A₀⋅BI ⋅k₁⋅k₃⋅k₄ - A₀⋅BI⋅B₀⋅k₁⋅k₃⋅k₄ + BI ⋅k₁⋅k₃⋅k₄ - BI ⋅k₂⋅k₃  - BI ⋅B₀⋅k₁⋅k₃⋅k₄ + 2⋅BI ⋅B₀⋅k₂⋅k₃  - BI ⋅I₀⋅k₁⋅k₃⋅k₄ + BI ⋅I₀

      2     2      2     2                 2      2                                       2                      2         2⎞
⋅k₂⋅k₃  - BI ⋅k₁⋅k₄  + BI ⋅k₂⋅k₃⋅k₄ - BI⋅B₀ ⋅k₂⋅k₃  + BI⋅B₀⋅I₀⋅k₁⋅k₃⋅k₄ - 2⋅BI⋅B₀⋅I₀⋅k₂⋅k₃  - BI⋅B₀⋅k₂⋅k₃⋅k₄ + B₀ ⋅I₀⋅k₂⋅k₃ ⎠
```

Maybe that solution is enough for you. The other three are significantly more complicated. You can get them all with:

```
In [85]: BI1, BI2, BI3, BI4 = roots(p, BI)                                                                                                     

In [86]: BI1                                                                                                                                   
Out[86]: B₀
```

I won't show the output for `BI2` etc because it's too complicated. Not all of these roots will necessarily be solutions of the original system because of the transformations done to get to them so you'd have to work backwards to figure out which are.

I think this means that the `BI = B0` solution is only valid if `B0` or `k4` is zero for example:

```
In [99]: eq2.subs(BI, BI1)                                                                                                                     
Out[99]: -B₀⋅k₄
```

EDIT: My answer above is intended to show how to get to the general symbolic answer but that does not seem to be what you actually want (the answer is too complicated to be of much use anyway). Since you want to get the answer for particular numbers you should just substitute those numbers into the equations. You can just use nsolve if you are not looking for the analytic solution:

```
In [29]: import sympy 
    ...: from sympy import solve, factor, roots, nonlinsolve 
    ...: A, B, I, AI, BI, A0, B0, I0, k1, k2, k3, k4 = sympy.symbols('A B I AI BI A_0 B_0 I_0 k1 k2 k3 k4', positive=True) 
    ...: eqs = [A0 - AI - A, 
    ...: B0 - BI - B, 
    ...: I0 - AI - BI - I, 
    ...: k1*(A0 - AI)*I - k2*AI, 
    ...: k3*(B0 - BI)*I - k4*BI]                                                                                                               

In [30]: inputs = [{A0: 100, B0: 100, I0: 100, k1: 0.1, k2: 0.1, k3: 0.1, k4: 0.1}, 
    ...:           {A0: 100, B0: 100, I0: 100, k1: 0.2, k2: 0.1, k3: 0.3, k4: 0.4}]                                                            

In [31]: eqs_sub = [eq.subs(inputs[0]) for eq in eqs]                                                                                          

In [32]: solve(eqs_sub, [A, B, I, AI, BI])                                                                                                     
Out[32]: [(50.4902894311622, 50.4902894311622, 0.980578862324382, 49.5097105688378, 49.5097105688378)]

In [33]: nsolve(eqs_sub, [A, B, I, AI, BI], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1])                                                                                   
Out[33]: 
⎡50.4902894311622 ⎤
⎢                 ⎥
⎢50.4902894311622 ⎥
⎢                 ⎥
⎢0.980578862324382⎥
⎢                 ⎥
⎢49.5097105688378 ⎥
⎢                 ⎥
⎣49.5097105688378 ⎦

In [34]: eqs_sub = [eq.subs(inputs[1]) for eq in eqs]                                                                                          

In [35]: nsolve(eqs_sub, [A, B, I, AI, BI], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1])                                                                                   
Out[35]: 
⎡38.3817627411582⎤
⎢                ⎥
⎢62.4209392826439⎥
⎢                ⎥
⎢0.80270202380213⎥
⎢                ⎥
⎢61.6182372588418⎥
⎢                ⎥
⎣37.5790607173561⎦
```

Comment: thank you, but I am interested in expressions for A, B, I, AI, BI in terms of the remaining variables (A0, B0, I0, k1, k2, k3, k4), so any expression that uses of A, B, I, AI, or BI is unfortunately of no use.

Comment: I have shown you (mostly) how to get to what you want. However the end result is quite complicated. Take a look at `BI2`. That gives `BI` in terms of the remaining variables as you ask. It's a complicated expression though and the others will be as well. That's why I haven't shown the final answer.

Comment: Thank you. Can you say a bit more on why these hand substitutions seem to work while the automated procedure used by nonlinsolve hangs? I don't follow that

Comment: also BI2 and the rest of the roots don't appear correct. ``BI2.subs({A0: 100, B0: 100, I0: 100, k1: 1.0, k2: 1.0, k3: 1.0, k4: 1.0})`` yields ``nan``. all positive reals should give a positive real answer here. not sure what went wrong.

Comment: The nonlinsolve function is slow for this case because it is computing a large Groebner basis as I said.

Comment: It's possible that the form of the answer is valid for most but not all values of the parameters. Note that if you substitute those values into the equations then `nonlinsolve(eqs, [A, B, AI, BI, I])` will succeed quickly.

Comment: i don't really understand why it produces a partially valid answer. if you have any suggestions on how to get a general expression assuming all variables are positive reals (and all solutions are real) i'd be grateful. when i try feeding in three of the 7 input variables it also fails to give correct resolutions: ``BI2.subs({A0: 100, B0: 100, I0: 100, k1: k1, k2: k2, k3: k3, k4: k4})``

Comment: The answer might e.g. divide by `A0 - B0` which would be valid for most values of those parameters but not if you set both to 100. It is possible in sympy to guard formulas like that using Piecewise but that would make the result even more complicated.

Comment: You can get the solutions for the final polynomials with `solve([eq1, eq2], [AI, BI], check=False)`

Comment: thank you again. ``solve([eq1, eq2], [AI, BI], check=False)`` returns solutions, if I plug in, say, values of A0, B0, I0, but all the solutions give nonsensical answers once I pick substitute values for k1, k2, k3, k4. They all evaluate to ``nan`` if I plug in any values. I don't know enough about how sympy works to debug, it's over my head, so I'll give up unfortunately.

Comment: Maybe it fails because sympy doesn't know the constraint that all the vars are positive reals.

Comment: You haven't declared them as positive.

Comment: If all you are going to do is substitute values in to the solution it is better to substitute those values into the equations before calling solve. The analytic solution can be more useful when it has a simple form but it does not in this case.

Comment: To be clear you get nan because of the particular values you are substituting which correspond to a degenerate case for the system of equations. If you set k4 to something other than 1 you will not get nan. Otherwise you should substitute k4=1 before calling solve which will give a different form of solution.

Comment: I have edited my question to reflect your helpful suggestions.

Comment: I've added something that shows how to get numerical answers for the parameters you suggest

Comment: thank you. it's not what I am looking for but very helpful so I am accepting the answer.